# Lambda function to get the sum of lengths of all the lists in a nested list?

Tags: python, lambda

```
get_total_length([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]])
```

I am new to lambda functions. How to make a lambda function to get the sum of lengths of the lists in a nested list. For the above mentioned example the result should be 10.

Comment: How deeply nested can you get? Writing a lambda for this gets harder if you need to go deeper than two dimensions. Do you need `get_total_length([[[[[[[1]]]]]]])` to work?

Answer (score 4):

In a generator expression, calculate the `len` of each sublist, then pass that into the `sum` function.

```
>>> values = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
>>> sum(len(i) for i in values)
10
```

As a `lambda` function

```
>>> get_total_length = lambda values: sum(len(i) for i in values)
>>> get_total_length([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]])
10
```

Comment: I was hoping to use map, but this works too. @CoryKramer Thanks!

Comment: With `map`, it would just be `sum(map(len, values))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion with a `lambda` function to find the length of a nested structure:

```
data = [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]], [[[[[[[1]]]]]]]]
full_length = lambda x:sum(1 if not isinstance(i, list) else full_length(i) for i in x)
print(list(map(full_length, data)))
```

Output:

```
[10, 1]
```